# Force CSS transition to complete at start and end of API call. Now it just flickers quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I have a API-call which fetches data at a 30 seconds interval, and i have a transition on the elements which updates so that the user can see when it's updated..

The problem is that the API-call is done too quickly for a smooth and nice CSS Transition of the elements..

How can i "force" the animation to complete no matter if the API-call returns data quicker ?

**API-call function :**

```
function forceUpdateCount() {
        startAnimateCounters();
        var urlForCount = 'api/Order/GetOrderStatusCount';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: urlForCount,
            success: function (data) {
                countmodel.nrOfNewOrders(data.countNewOrders);
                countmodel.nrOfInProgress(data.countInProgress);
                countmodel.nrOfReadyForPickup(data.countReadyForPickup);
                countmodel.nrOfInTransport(data.countInTransport);
                countmodel.nrOfCompleted(data.countCompletedOrders);
                countmodel.nrOfCancelled(data.countCancelledOrders);
                countmodel.lastUpdated(getLastUpdated());

                endAnimateCounters();
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    }
```

**Function for animation :**

```
function startAnimateCounters() {
    $('.count-body.slateblueish').addClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.yellowish').addClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.slategreenish').addClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.beigeish').addClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.greenish').addClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.redish').addClass('whiteanimated');
};

function endAnimateCounters() {
    $('.count-body.slateblueish').removeClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.yellowish').removeClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.slategreenish').removeClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.beigeish').removeClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.greenish').removeClass('whiteanimated');
    $('.count-body.redish').removeClass('whiteanimated');
};
```

**CSS-code :**

```
.yellowish {
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
    background-color: #ffef96;
}

.whiteanimated {
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
    background: #ffffff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't work with CSS runtime variables, you can't do that. What you may do is to creating a CSS animation that doesn't mean 0% to 100% complete, maybe a loading icon with an animation.. When you're dealing with asynchronous things, there's no way to assume a response time. Maybe this could help https://icons8.com/preloaders/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rodolfo :) I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can simply be described as having two separate, future conditions that both have to be met in order for a specific action to take place. The action is that the "out" transition should happen, one of the conditions is that the AJAX request has completed and the other condition is that the "in" transition has completed. This is something `Promise`s are very well suited for.

The idea is to create a `Promise` for each of the two conditions and resolve it when the condition is met, then trigger the "out" transition when both promises have resolved:

```
function forceUpdateCount() {

    // Create a promise that gets resolved when the transition has completed
    var transitionPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        $('.count-body.yellowish').one('transitionend', resolve);
    }

    startAnimateCounters();
    var urlForCount = 'api/Order/GetOrderStatusCount';

    // $.ajax() already returns a promise, we'll use that
    var requestPromise = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: urlForCount,
        success: function (data) {
            countmodel.nrOfNewOrders(data.countNewOrders);
            countmodel.nrOfInProgress(data.countInProgress);
            countmodel.nrOfReadyForPickup(data.countReadyForPickup);
            countmodel.nrOfInTransport(data.countInTransport);
            countmodel.nrOfCompleted(data.countCompletedOrders);
            countmodel.nrOfCancelled(data.countCancelledOrders);
            countmodel.lastUpdated(getLastUpdated());
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });

    // Wrap both promises with Promise.all() to get a new promise that resolves when both of the wrapped promises have resolved
    Promise.all([ transitionPromise, requestPromise ]).then(endAnimateCounters);
}
```

We use the `transitionend` event on one of the animated elements to signal that the condition for the "in" transition has been met.

`Promise.all()` takes a list of promises and returns a new promise that gets resolved when all of the promises in the list has resolved. When that happens, the callback function passed to the `then()` method gets executed, which in our case is the `endAnimateCounters` function that we moved out of the request's success callback.

More on `Promise`s: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise